# Transferring files between two remote servers that use different protocols

Tags: ftp, sftp

Is it possible to directly transfer files between two remote servers when they don't use the same protocol? I have a lot of files on serverA (which, at least for now, must be accessed using SFTP) and want to copy them to serverB (which must be accessed using FTP). Unfortunately, I can't do anything on the servers themselves as I am an external client for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I think you can do it with

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

followed by

```
mkdir serverAFiles
sshfs serverA:/path/to/the/directory serverAfiles
```

Now you will see the files on serverA in the 'serverAfiles' directory just as if they were on the local machine, and can ftp them onto serverB just as if they were local.

When you're done,

```
fusermount -u serverAfiles
```

will break the ssh connection and you'll no longer see the remote files as being local.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try when I get the chance. I hadn't even thought of mounting one of the servers.

Comment: It partly works. I can access the mounted system but only if I am doing it as root. Changing the permissions on the folder it is mounted to does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59685/sshfs-mount-sudo-gets-permission-denied).

Comment: Follow-up Question: According to the documentation, you are supposed to be able to use `ssh` options with `sshfs`. How do you do this? I have tried something like `-o User=joe` but then fuse gives me an error saying that `User` is not a recognized option.