# How do I specify SSH options for SSHFS?

Tags: sshfs

I had originally asked this as a follow-up question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971470/transferring-files-between-two-remote-servers-that-use-different-protocols). Unfortunately, there haven't been any replies so I am posting it as its own question.

According to the [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sshfs.1.html), you are supposed to be able to use `ssh` options with `sshfs`. How do you do this? I have tried something like `-o User=joe` but then fuse gives me an error saying that "User" is not a recognized option.

Also, help with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974456/using-ftpes-with-curlftpfs) would also be appreciated.

---

Edit:

I am specifically referring to the following from the manpage for sshfs.

> SSHFS options:
>
> ```
>   -p PORT
>          equivalent to '-o port=PORT'
>
>   -C     equivalent to '-o compression=yes'
>
>   ⋮
>
>   -o password_stdin
>          read password from stdin (only for pam_mount!)
>
>   -o SSHOPT=VAL
>          ssh options (see man ssh_config)
> ```

I am trying to specify the remote username separate from the host (in other words, not `user@host:dir`). The reason is that particular format is not friendly with some institutionally assigned usernames. For example, if the institution assigns the user name `Fist.Last@institution.edu`, programs such as sshfs and curlftpfs will not correctly interpret `First.Last@institution.edu@host:dir`. Instead, they will try to login as `First.Last` to the host `institution.edu@host`.

Could you explain a bit more about `idmap`? I am not literate enough to understand what the manpage is saying.

---

Edit:

If I use `idmap`, I am going to have to create hardcoded files. I was hoping to avoid that so that the user can just use a single command without needing to know how it works in the background. Eventually, other people might be using it even after I leave. Even so, the documentation says the file format is `username:uid`. Which is the local and which is remote?

Comment: That is how you specify options, I don't think user=joe is a valid option. My guess is you want `-o idmap=user` . See the man page for valid mount options https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs or update your question as I am not sure what your problem is other than an invalid option or if you need to manually map users

Comment: @Panther Updated.

Comment: Take a look at the arch sshfs page I don't have time to write a long answer right now

Comment: wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#Secure_user_access

Comment: idmap only takes none, user, or file explicitly as options, you can't give it a userid.

Comment: @Panther Updated

Comment: I think you can use quoted username: `sshfs 'user.name'@host.name:/remote/dir /local/dir ` Or you could use [`~/.ssh/config` file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client). But I do not think the username actually have a dot in it - [click here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25956859/). How did you create the user? What is the output of `echo $USER`?

Comment: The issue is less of the username itself and more of having an alternative means of entering it.

Comment: I just tried the normal format again and it worked this time. Perhaps it was an issue with the server.

Answer (score 8):

To pass SSH options to SSHFS, you can use `ssh_command`.

For example, to pass `-c aes128-cbc` to SSH, use:

```
sshfs -o ssh_command='ssh -c aes128-cbc' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options you can pass right away:
-p PORT (to change the ssh port from the default 22)
-C (to specify you want compression)

Comment: sshfs -p 2233 user@192.168.1.2: /mnt/point      just for an example

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR: For options requiring a path, use absolute paths.

This bit of sshfs' man page suggest that it should just work fine with `-o`:

```
  -o SSHOPT=VAL
         ssh options (see man ssh_config)
```

However, I had troubles passing in a certificate file with `-o CertificateFile=path/to/cert`.  It turns out that it only works with an absolute path to the certificate file, while plain `ssh` happily accepts a relative path.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Apparently that was me, and I don't remember doing it. If you make a bogus edit the site will let me withdraw the downvote.